# eclipse is showing error "missing EOF in '@'" in css file

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx

I'm making a standalone Java application using the JavaFX.For designing layout it use css file. So I made a custom css design. In that for adding font from external link this is what I write

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'CustomFont';
src: url('CustomFont.TTF');
}
.list-view {
-fx-font-size: 12pt;
-fx-font-family: "CustomFont";
-fx-text-fill: #0080ff;
}
```

But  in eclipse it is showing there is an error on the line @font-face.It is showing that  "missing EOF in '@'". 
If i compile the whole project it works properly.But I wanted to remove that annoying error message.Any solution.

Comment: If you are plugging this code directly into eclipse in probably won't work, the reason being; the **@** symbol is used to indicate annotation types. Anything following the **@** symbol is expected to be a part of the annotation.

Comment: @EvanBechtol I assume this is a CSS file, not a Java source file.

Comment: @James_D I think you are right, I misread the questions :x

Would an '@Suppress' work in this case?

Comment: Does it show up in the Problems view? What kind of Problem does it say it is? The CSS editor doesn't offer validation, so something else must be doing it.

Comment: these are the image of the problem

http://i.imgur.com/b02pFUK.png

http://i.imgur.com/P4KCNP1.png

Comment: @nitind these are the image of the problemi.imgur.com/b02pFUK.png i.imgur.com/P4KCNP1.png